# Ngrx makes my dispatched object read only

Tags: angular, ngrx

I've got the following lines of code:

```
this.carInformation.subModel = [this.submodel.value]; 
this.store.dispatch(saveCriteria({ criteria: this.carInformation }));
```

When my app re-runs these two lines, I get the following error on the first line:

Cannot assign to read only property 'subModel' of object '[object Object]'

Why is carInformation suddenly read only?

I did notice using the following line of code that the writable property of my object is now false:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.carInformation, 'subModel');
```

I managed to fix this by moving the dispatch elsewhere, but I would've figured that I could re-edit my object and re-dispatch it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular ngrx: assign a readonly property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404762/angular-ngrx-assign-a-readonly-property)

Comment: Additionally, here are a couple more of resources that can help you.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591012/ngrx-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-property-of-object-object) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62066775/11755228). I recommend reading the "Link 2" as it is golden IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference of `this.submodel.value` is dispatched to the store.
Because the store has immutable runtime checks, that reference is "locked" and throws if it's changed.